# Is it possible to update WikiData by API?

Tags: wikipedia, wikidata

I have a few thousand edits that I could do:

- adding a wikidata id for wikipedia pages that do not gave one
- editing the instance of property for a number (of those and pre-existing ones)

This is data I have that comes from analysing extracts of pages via NLP.

I am not inclined to do that by hand - is there an API to do that?

Comment: Sure, being machine-processing-friendly is the whole point of Wikidata. You can find the docs [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/API).

Comment: @Tgr thanks! I'd googled for wikidata API until now. They're kinda hidden. If you turn the comment into an answer I can accept it and others will be able to find it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The software behind Wikidata is called Wikibase; it's API documentation can be found at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/API.

Wikibase was designed to be machine-friendly, so any action can be performed via the API (although the syntax is not the most intuitive). There is also a wide array of [tools](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Tools) for the API, from client libraries to GUI-based editors to integration with external systems like Google Sheets.